# Show certain part of the image with photoview (basePosition and initialScale)

Tags: image, flutter

I want to show certain part of the image. I started to use photoview library, because you can set basePosition and initialScale.

So I defined a rectangle within the image: top-left position, width and height. (contentPosX, contentPosY, contentWidth, contentHeight)

I have an image like that with a certain part (right side mushroom):

[image]
I calculate center of my rectangle (Aligment value range [-1;1]):

```
double alignmentX = ((contentPosX + contentWidth / 2) / imageWidth) * 2 - 1;
double alignmentY = ((contentPosY + contentHeight / 2) / imageHeight) * 2 - 1;
```

And a zoom factor:

```
double zoom = imageHeight / contentHeight;
```

As you can see below, I do not get the result what I expect. It is a little shifted. What am I missing? 
I am not depend of photoview library, if there another way to solve this issue, it is welcomed!

[image]

Here it is a working dummy part of my code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Photoview problem"),
      ),
      body: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _buildGridItem(context, index),
        staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
          final imageWidth = 2048;
          final imageHeight = 1536;
          final contentPosX = 1067;
          final contentPosY = 275;
          final contentWidth = 766;
          final contentHeight = 820;
          return StaggeredTile.count(1, contentHeight / contentWidth);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGridItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    final imageWidth = 2048;
    final imageHeight = 1536;
    final contentPosX = 1067;
    final contentPosY = 275;
    final contentWidth = 766;
    final contentHeight = 820;
    double zoom = imageHeight / contentHeight;
    double alignmentX = ((contentPosX + contentWidth / 2) / imageWidth) * 2 - 1;
    double alignmentY = ((contentPosY + contentHeight / 2) / imageHeight) * 2 - 1;
    return ClipRect(
      child: PhotoView(
        basePosition: Alignment(alignmentX, alignmentY),
        initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * zoom,
        imageProvider: AssetImage('assets/image.jpg'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```